# Show the set of $n × m$ matrices of rank at most $k < min(m, n)$ is not a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

How to the set of $n × m$ matrices of rank at most $k < min(m, n)$ is not a linear space? From Quora, I found an answer that any $n,m$ matrices form a linear space. So is it correct?[[1]](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-set-of-Matrices-over-the-Reals-a-vector-space)

I started my work with the following setting. There I considered two matrices A, B which are $4,3$ size and rank is 2.

A = $\begin{matrix}\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&1&0\\1&2&0\end{matrix}$

B = $\begin{matrix}\\1&1&0\\0&1&0\\1&2&0\\-1&0&0\end{matrix}$

Then I will take $\lambda=2$ and find $A+\lambda B$. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the axioms for what makes a vector space?

Comment: The two matrices you chose to work with share a third column of zeros, so any linear combination of those particular $4\times 3$ matrices would again have a third column of zeros.  So those matrices will satisfy rank less than $\min(4,3)$.  But the proposition more generally is false.  The sum of two rank deficient matrices can have full rank, and you should try to find such a pair.

Comment: Hint: Every $n \times m$-matrix is a sum of $nm$ many matrices of rank $1$. What would this mean if the matrices of rank $\leq k$ formed a vector subspace?

Comment: It **is** a linear space if $k=0$.